# UserControl.OnLoad not called on a UserControl in a System.Windows.Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ProjectViewForm`, a `ProjectView`, and a `Project`. The `ProjectView.OnLoad` method is not called and causes the application to crash when attempting to show the `ProjectViewForm`, for lack of initialization and data.

How to I get the `ProjectView` object initialized with `Project` data, ie. how do I get `OnLoad` to be called?

```
[SmartPart]
public partial class ProjectViewForm : Form
{
    public ProjectViewForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // gets here
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(""); // doesn't get here
    }
}

public partial class ProjectView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    public ProjectView()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       ...
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
            this._presenter.OnViewReady();
            base.OnLoad(eventArgs);
            ... populate with Project data ...
    }
}
```

`Project` is a POCO whose data populates `ProjectView`

In the ProjectViewForm.Designer.cs, a new `Project` and `ProjectView` are instantiated:

```
partial class ProjectViewForm
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Project project1 = new Project();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new 
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ProjectViewForm));
        this.projectView1 = new ProjectView();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        this.projectView1.SomeComponent1 = null;
        this.projectView1.SomeComponent2 = null;
        ...
        project1.SomeProperty1 = null;
        project1.SomeProperty2 = null;
        ...
        this.Controls.Add(this.projectView1);

        this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

    private ProjectView projectView1;
}
```

In the Controller, I have this code:

```
 WorkItem.State["CurrentProject"] = project; // Project to display
 string key = System.String.Concat("ProjectViewForm", project.Id);
 ProjectViewForm projectViewForm = WorkItem.Items.Get<ProjectViewForm>(key);  // calls ProjectViewForm constructor
 if (projectViewForm == null)
 {
     projectViewForm = WorkItem.Items.AddNew<ProjectViewForm>(key);
 }
 else
 {
     projectViewForm.Focus();
 }

 projectViewForm.Enter += ProjectViewForm_Enter;
 projectViewForm.Leave += ProjectViewForm_Leave;

 string formTitle = System.String.Concat (project.Name, " - Status: ", project.ProjectStatusType.Text);
 var info = new Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.WinForms.WindowSmartPartInfo();
 info.Location = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
 ... yadda yadda yadda ...
 projectViewForm.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

WorkItem.Workspaces[Infrastructure.Interface.Constants.WorkspaceNames.WindowsWorkspace].Show (projectViewForm, info);
```

Comment: Are you saying if you put a debug stop in the OnLoad method of that UserControl, it's never stopping there?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: We can't recreate something like that on our end.

Comment: So you are saying that given the code you see, `OnLoad` should be being called? If that's the case, there must be something I need to do in the Designer.

Comment: Is the UserControl in a TabControl?  Can't the OnLoad code be moved to the UserControl's constructor?  Which line throws the exception?

Comment: As already described, `OnLoad` is called when the control is first shown, thus when its Container is shown. Otherwise, only the constructor is called when the Container initializes its controls (or your code initializes it explicitly).

Comment: The `ProjectView` constructor is being called explicitly. I've added some to code to show `ProjectViewForm.Designer.cs`. I think part of my problem is that I need to get the `Project` data to ProjectView. I don't know how to do that with this ` ProjectViewForm projectViewForm = WorkItem.Items.Get<ProjectViewForm>(key);` way of doing things. The exception is thrown when showing the `ProjectViewForm`

Comment: I want to take back the 'get the Project data to ProjectView' statement I think. This done in `ProjectView.OnLoad' but it is not being called. If I understand @Jimi correctly, when `Show` is called for `ProjectViewForm`, this should cause `Show` for `ProjectView` to be called and consequently `OnLoad` but that is not happening.

Comment: Do you ever add the `ProjectView` to the form's `Components` collection? It's not there in the `InitializeComponents` you show.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It added, I just didn't show it, but I'll show it now.

Comment: In fact, it is not getting to `ProjectViewForm.OnLoad()` (much less `ProjectView.OnLoad()`. So something is really wrong. I've added to code to show`ProjectViewForm.OnLoad()`